Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined en vite cuando se hace npm run build
Estoy tratando de comprimir todas las dependencias de una plantilla que tiene bootstrap 5 y estoy usando vite para ellos cuando ejecuto npm run dev no me da ningun problema pero cuando hago el npm run build me da el siguiente error.
(function(o, ue) {
    typeof nn == "object" && typeof Et < "u" ? Et.exports = ue(require("@popperjs/core")) : typeof define == "function" && define.amd ? define(["@popperjs/core"], ue) : (o = typeof globalThis < "u" ? globalThis : o || self).bootstrap = ue(o.Popper)
}

Tengo lo siguientes archivos para las importaciones globales llamado dependencies.js que tiene lo siguiente :
import $ from 'jquery';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
import toastr from 'toastr';
import axios, {isCancel, AxiosError} from 'axios';
import { initAxios } from './js/custom_actions.js';

window.$         = window.jQuery = $;
window.axios     = axios;
window.Swal      = Swal;
window.toastr    = toastr;
window.initAxios = initAxios;

y otro archivo llamado app.js donde llamo las dependencias globales y además las archivos que necesita la plantilla que es lo siguiente:
import './dependencies.js';

import './js/popper.min.js';
import './js/bootstrap.min.js';
import './js/DataTables.js';
import './js/DataTables.bootstrap.js';
import './js/DataTables.responsive.js'
import './js/responsive.bootstrap.js';
import './js/nifty.js';
import './js/demo-purpose-only.js';
import './js/jquery.autocomplete.js';
import './js/select2.min.js';
import './js/flatpickr.js';
import './js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';

import "./app.css";

y el archivo vite.conf.js lo tengo de esta forma:

esta es el codigo de mi plantilla base:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    {% block css %}
        {{ vite_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {{ vite_entry_script_tags('app') }}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

estoy usando el paquete de pentatrion/vite-bundle en symfony para el manejo de vite

Lee este hilo pueda que te ayude...

Segui todos los pasos que dicen pero aun me sigue dando el problema cuando se hace el build para produccion

ya instale la dependencia de vite-plugin-node-polyfills  pero perciste el problema

ya pude resolver el problema tuve que instalar la siguiente dependencia y además de agregar agregar alias de la siguiente manera:
resolve:{
   alias:{
      'datatables.net': path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/DataTables.js')
   }
 }

debido que yo tengo los archivos localmente y ya cuando preparo los archivos para subir a producción ya no me da error
